# Force default reevaluation on function call

Tags: python

AFAIK, Python evaluates the defaults of a function only once, at declaration time. So calling the following function `printRandom`

```
import random
def printRandom(randomNumber = random.randint(0, 10)):
    print randomNumber
```

will print the *same* number each time called without arguments. Is there a way to force reevaluation of the default `randomNumber` at each function call without doing it manually? Below is what I mean by "manually":

```
import random
def printRandom(randomNumber):
    if not randomNumber:
         randomNumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    print randomNumber
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The default arguments are set when they are executed, which is when the function is defined. If you wanted them to be re-executed, you would need to re-define the function.

The standard idiom, and the one you should use, is

```
import random
def print_random(random_number=None):
    if random_number is None:
        random_number = 4 # chosen by fair dice roll.
                          # guaranteed to be random.
    print random_number
```

Note the use of `None` (a singleton) and the `is` test for object identity. You shouldn't use `if not random_number` since there are many values which evaluate to boolean false -- in particular, `0`.

There are plenty of other ways you *could* do this, but there's no reason not to follow the convention.

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between `random_number == None` and `random_number is None`?

Comment: He already said that in his answer but well: `is` is the test for object _identity_, while `==` checks two objects for _equality_. `1.0 is 1 == False` while `(1.0 == 1) == True`.

Comment: That's a [common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) :p. In short, `==` tests whether the objects are _semantically equal_ (i.e. hold the same data), and `is` tests whether they are _the same object_. In comparing to `None` you should use `is`; this is one of the few cases where you should do so :p.

Comment: You will probably never see a difference in your code between `==None` and `is None`, but it is possible: a class which overrides `__eq__` might compare equal to `None` (see [this blog post](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html)). But in general you should use `is` here because PEP 8 says to.

Answer (score 3):

Use `None`:

```
def printRandom(randomNumber=None):
    if randomNumber is None:
        randomNumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    print randomNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best bet would be to define `None` as default value for randomNumber.

```
def printRandom(randomNumber=None):
    if randomNumber is None:
        print random.randint(0, 10)
    else:
        print randomNumber
```